# Is 12/2 cable to subpanel ok?

Tags: wiring, subpanel

My gf's 1940s house in the US. The house is on a newer 200amp box, but the garage has the old glass screw-in fuse box. The main supply coming into the garage is 12/2 and appears to be tied into the kitchen lighting. As far as I can tell (but not 100% positive), the garage and kitchen light are the only things on this 20amp breaker. As for the box in the garage, the supply goes into a 25amp fuse (already a bad sign) with 4 other fuses (15 and 20) running to everything else in the garage, which is just an opener, some lights, and a few outlets.  We think the garage was originally a lean-to and someone enclosed it and ran power themselves and feel this fuse box needs replaced. The wires are in good condition at least and not the older cloth wrapped stuff.

I have a new box with 6 spaces laying around I can use; [homeline 100amp](https://www.homedepot.com/p/100190554)

If I install a ground bar (not bonded to the neutral) and run my only hot wire to just one of the bars and only use those 3 slots, is that ok?  Can a wire be used to jump to the other bar?

The entire garage would be perfectly fine on a single 20amp breaker, not sure why the fuse box was ever put in to begin with.

Here's what the box looks like:
[image]

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't spend time installing such a tiny panel. You can get bundles containing a 12 or 14-space panel and several breakers for about $50 (or bigger for a little more). Sell the 6-space unit on Craigslist to some other sucker (or return it if you can), and the bigger panel bundle will only cost you a few bucks more than you were going to have to spend on breakers alone.

Comment: Pigtail the black wire so that it connects to *both* of the line terminals.  (Sometimes the terminal lends itself to a wire going "thru", in which case you can strip insulation there and keep going to the other terminal. Otherwise pigtail - DO NOT land 2 wires on the lug, they are not rated for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

12/2 is perfectly legitimate, but obviously gives you a max of 20A @ 120V. Putting in  a new subpanel does make sense. You can jumper the two hots together to make all 6 spaces active, but unless the lugs are rated for two wires, you would do that with a pigtail.

While you do already have this panel isn't very big, it is big enough that you could later add an EV charging circuit, provided that you upgrade the feed from the main panel.

Also keep in mind that even a small panel needs sufficient workspace in front of it. I assume a car parked in front of it is not an issue (but I could be wrong), but any real "storage" is.

Answer (score 2):

If everything is protected by a single 20A breaker in the main panel and if that is adequate, why not just repurpose the garage fuse box as a junction box?  Strip out all the innards and replace with two wire nuts.

Later if you need more power you can run a new feeder and design it properly with actual requirements in mind.

Comment: I've already swapped it out, but in hindsight that probably would've been a good idea. Since I already had the panel laying around not being used I threw that up there.